# Sass Foundation Underscores Project Structure, removing git folder and package.json file

Tags: wordpress, git, sass, zurb-foundation, gulp

I am attempting a test dev setup of a foundation/underscores wordpress theme.

I have a wordpress install, and to that I added an underscores theme. I then made a folder in this called foundation and installed foundation ( sass using bower ) into that.

I will get it all working and hooked up using gulp, but I notice that Foundation placed a git file in the foundation folder. I have used git in the past but I'm unsure of what options I have here. Ideally I want to remove the git repo. Then at that point I would be doing a git init from the main theme folder ( the foundation sub folder I intend to only use for the sass source files). **My quesion is ... Is there any issue with doing it this way.** I essentially want to get rid of the git repo that came down with the foundation install and setup my own git repo manually; ( which will also cover the underscores and my own custom files in the parent directory)

**My directory structure looks like this:**

- wp-content

  - themes

    - my_theme ( underscores) ( new git repo here )

      - foundation folder ( git repo here which I want to remove )

I also want to remove the package.json file and gruntfile because I hope to use gulp instead ( again from the main theme folder not the foundation directory )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're planning on hacking on the foundation code I wouldn't recommend this. There will be issues if you decide to upgrade to a newer version of foundation using bower. If you are working on this with another developer and choose to pursue this route I'd recommend removing the dependency from your `bower.json` file.

Comment: I was planning on leaving the bower.json file; surely that's all that bower needs ... would bower need the git repo? If so would I then be OK leaving that git repo there and starting another one in the parent `my_theme` folder. I definitely want to be able to update foundation via bower ... how would you recommend I set it up if you think this wouldn't work

Comment: If you're not going to change the foundation code I would leave the git repo there, create your own repo in the base of your theme and add the folder with your bower dependencies to your `.gitignore` file.. that way if someone is collaborating with you they just have to run `bower install` to get the dependencies (in this case foundation). If you need help creating the `.gitignore` file, check out [this](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Thanks ... no I do understand how to do gitingore; and that idea makes sense to me ... now would you say that this method is a pretty sound method? The other way I could do this would be to add the contents of the underscore theme into the foundation folder and use that as the folder directory instead. I'm sure it would work but foundation and underscores would be "mixed" then which I presume is not as good, and both have a js folder too. Could you tell me if your way is better than this way ... and if you know of any other methods I might consider. Thanks